# Wait for two completion handlers?

Tags: swift, completionhandler

Inside my app, I do few requests to my back-end. In one case I have a function that should return two parameters (may be `Bool` and `Bool` for example). But there comes my problem. To return those two parameters, I need to receive some info from back-end first, so it would look like this (will be written in pseudo-swift-code):

```
func request() -> (Bool, Bool) {
    var one: Bool?
    var two: Bool?

    Alamofire.request(url1).response { (response) in
        if let response = response { one = response }
    }

    Alamofire.request(url2).response { (response) in
        if let response = response { two = response }
    }

    if let one = one, let two = two {
        return (one, two)
    }

    return (nil, nil)
}
```

How do I achieve a function that waits for those two web requests?

Comment: The call is async and you are trying to return a data synchronous. this cant happen

Comment: I guess there are several ways to tackle this, one of which is any library that implements the async/await or promises pattern. [Here is a nice one](https://github.com/freshOS/then)

Answer (score 4):

Usually, when facing such a case, you would not be able to -directly- return a value from a function. I would suggest that you should follow the approach of making a *callback* for the method instead (using `@escaping` closure).

On the other hand, you'd need to execute the callback when both of the requests are done. One of the possible solutions is to use dispatch group (you could check: [Call completion block when two other completion blocks have been called](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41809000/call-completion-block-when-two-other-completion-blocks-have-been-called/41809248#41809248)).

For putting all together, your function could be look like this:

```
func request(callback: @escaping (_ one: Bool?,  _ two: Bool?) -> Void) {
    var one: Bool?
    var two: Bool?

    let group = DispatchGroup()

    group.enter()
    Alamofire.request(url1).response { (response) in
        if let response = response { one = response }
        group.leave()
    }

    group.enter()
    Alamofire.request(url2).response { (response) in
        if let response = response { two = response }
        group.leave()
    }

    group.notify(queue: DispatchQueue.main) {
        if let one = one, let two = two {
            callback(one, two)
        } else {
            callback(nil, nil)
        }
    }
}
```

Thus you would call it as:

```
request { (one, two) in
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
func request() -> (Bool?, Bool?) {
    var one: Bool?
    var two: Bool?
    let semaphore = DispatchSemaphore(value: 0)
    Alamofire.request(url1).response { (response) in
        if let response = response { one = response }
        semaphore.signal()
    }
    Alamofire.request(url2).response { (response) in
        if let response = response { two = response }
        semaphore.signal()
    }
    _ = semaphore.wait(timeout: DispatchTime.distantFuture)
    _ = semaphore.wait(timeout: DispatchTime.distantFuture)
    if let one = one, let two = two {
        return (one, two)
    }
    return (nil, nil)
}
```

Comment: I think reviewing [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49923810/when-to-use-semaphore-instead-of-dispatch-group) would lead to a pretty cool discussion ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this

```
var one: Bool?
var two: Bool?

func request() {

    Alamofire.request(url1).response { (response) in
        if let response = response { one = response }
        processResponse()
    }

    Alamofire.request(url2).response { (response) in
        if let response = response { two = response }
        processResponse()
    }
}

func processResponse() {
    if let one = one, let two = two {
        // do something
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below:

```
func request(completion: ((Bool?, Bool?) -> Void)?) {
    var one: Bool?
    var two: Bool?

    Alamofire.request(url1).response { (response) in
        if let response = response { one = response }
        Alamofire.request(url2).response { (response) in
             if let response = response { two = response }

             completion?(one, two)
        }
   }
}
```

Comment: This solution defines the direction of requests

Comment: 2 comments on this solution: 1- it is **slower**, you are following the approach of serializing the process (which is not the wanted behavior). Instead, both of requests should work in parallel. 2- It's illegal! it won't work as expected because `completion` *not* escaping by default :)