# is anyone able to restrict the type of the objects dropped on the mac in SwiftUI 3?

Tags: macos, types, swiftui, drop

as per the documentation, it should be pretty straightforward. example for a `List`: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/list/ondrop(of:istargeted:perform:)-75hvy#

the `UTType` should be the parameter restricting what a SwiftUI object can receive. in my case i want to accept only `Apps`. the `UTType` is `.applicationBundle`: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uniformtypeidentifiers/uttype/3551459-applicationbundle

but it doesn't work. the SwiftUI object never changes status and never accepts the drop. the closure is never run. whether on `Lists`, `H/VStacks`, `Buttons`, whatever. the `pdf` type don't seem to work either, as well as many others. the only type that i'm able to use if `fileURL`, which is mainly like no restriction.

i'm not sure if i'm doing something wrong or if SwiftUI is half working for the mac.

here's the code:

```swift
List(appsToIgnore, id: \.self, selection: $selection) {
    Text($0)
}
.onDrop(of: [.applicationBundle, .application], isTargeted: isTargeted) { providers in
    print("hehe")
    
    return true
}
```

replacing or just adding `.fileURL` in the `UTType` array makes the drop work but without any type restriction.

i've also tried to use `.onInsert` on a `ForEach` instead (https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/foreach/oninsert(of:perform:)-2whxl#), and to go through a proper DropDelegate (https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/dropdelegate#) but keep getting the same results. it would seem the SwiftUI drop for macOS is not yet working, but i can't find any official information about this. in the docs it is written `macOS 11.0+` so i would expect it to work?

any info appreciated! thanks.

Comment: If you drag from Finder then there is no `.application` in pasteboard, but `.fileURL` does exists. Why do you expect `.application`?

Comment: @Asperi so that's the thing. i was afraid i misunderstood something and it seems to be the case. i thought that specifying the UTType in the .onDrop was sufficient. i have/had no idea about what type showed up in the pasteboard. thanks for pointing this out. will investigate.

Comment: Can't you just check the dropped file's path to see if it has the .app extension or not?

Comment: @arata the idea is to prevent the ability to drop a file that is not an application, with the UI correctly updated (no + sign, etc...). the way to achieve that is through the `validateDrop` func, as @Asperi stated. if you return false from `validateDrop`, then the user can't drop the file and the UI is updated accordingly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to validate manually, using `DropDelegate` of what kind of file is dragged over.

Here is a simplified demo of possible approach. Tested with Xcode 13 / macOS 11.6

```
let delegate = MyDelegate()

...


List(appsToIgnore, id: \.self, selection: $selection) {
    Text($0)
}
.onDrop(of: [.fileURL], delegate: delegate) // << accept file URLs
```

and verification part like

```
class MyDelegate: DropDelegate {

    func validateDrop(info: DropInfo) -> Bool {
        // find provider with file URL
        guard info.hasItemsConforming(to: [.fileURL]) else { return false }
        guard let provider = info.itemProviders(for: [.fileURL]).first else { return false }

        var result = false
        if provider.canLoadObject(ofClass: String.self) {
            let group = DispatchGroup()
            group.enter()     // << make decoding sync

            // decode URL from item provider
            _ = provider.loadObject(ofClass: String.self) { value, _ in
                defer { group.leave() }
                guard let fileURL = value, let url = URL(string: fileURL) else { return }

                // verify type of content by URL
                let flag = try? url.resourceValues(forKeys: [.contentTypeKey]).contentType == .applicationBundle
                result = flag ?? false
            }

            // wait a bit for verification result
            _ = group.wait(timeout: .now() + 0.5)
        }
        return result
    }

    func performDrop(info: DropInfo) -> Bool {
        // handling code is here
        return true
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks. i definitely overlooked that `validateDrop` thing. will investigate, and mark the answer if that's what i'm looking for.

Comment: that works beautifully, thank you. i clearly misunderstood the `onDrop` parameters, and overlooked the `validateDrop`. this is exactly what i was looking for. thanks again!

Comment: i'm trying to reach that solution by myself from scratch and holy cow i'm realizing how this is golden. thanks a lot @Asperi :D

Comment: any reason why loadingObject of Class String rather than URL? wouldn't the second guard of the `validateDrop` func take care of making sure we get a URL?
(had no idea about DispatchGroup also. thanks. quite a few new learnings from your answer.)

Comment: @godbout I also recommend you to read about`DispatchSemaphore` if you haven't heard of it. You can read more here about `DispatchGroup` vs `DispatchSemaphore`: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49925414/6458677

Comment: i'm finding that this code is leaking. no idea yet where's the issue, but it seems related to DispatchGroup.